# Create a custom function in ember controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6

I have created a function for my ember app which do some calculation.But I am not able to use it.

Controller.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   ScaleImage(data) { 
      //maniplution with data 
   },
   feedResult:Ember.computed('model',function() {
      dimension = ScaleImage(data);
   });
});
```

It throws an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ScaleImage is not defined
```

If I put  function in separate file inside the bower_component and then call the function.It works fine.I want to include the function in my ember project.Because I think while building the ember app and delopying it.The separate function file will be left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the function as a property on the controller, if you want to use it you will need to call it by using `this.ScaleImage`.
Or by defining it as a function like so:

```
Controller.js

import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   feedResult:Ember.computed('model',function() {
      dimension = scaleImage(data);
   });
});

function scaleImage(data) {
  // your logic goes here
}
```

Keep in mind it is bad practice to have a function start with a capital letter, those are usually classes.

Comment: Thanks It worked.Can you solve one more query.I am using someting like this in my hbs.           <img id = "image1" src = "{{photo.0.photo_url}}" onload = "OnImageLoad(event);" {{action "imgOverlay0" photo}}/>
Now how and where should I define the OnImageLoad function.For now I have kept this file in bower_components and it works fine.

Comment: I would make an image component that handles the loading, inline js is rarely a good idea, if you could update you question with some more details I could help you with the component.

Comment: I have posted the question in detail.You can check through this link .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058754/use-onload-on-image-tag-in-ember

Comment: Check out my answer. It follows @Kitler's recommendation of using an ember component: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35078154/916734